# In a for loop is it advisable to convert the constants again and again, rather than declaring another variable before the loop starts

Tags: .net, performance, c#-3.0

```
for(int i=0;i<someDomain.count;i++)
{
   if(someDomain.someValue != Convert.ToInt32(DomainConstants.PaymentPending))
   {
      Dosomething...
    }
}
```

In this if the count is more, is it advisable to declare an integer for 'DomainConstants.PaymentPending' before the loop starts or this doesn't cause any performance hit. Sometimes the count may go to 100.

Comment: Declare a variable before. This way, the code will be clearer (if you name the variable correctly) and the execution will be faster. (OK for a loop from 0 to 100, performance improvement are not visible but still).

Comment: Thanks Cedrik ...
On top of this I would like to ask, Is there any article where we can find the best practices. For e.g should we use '==' or '.Equals'; 'using' or 'try catch'..

Comment: There are a lot of articles about best practices but I don't know any that gather them.

Comment: What's the type of `DomainConstants.PaymentPending`? `string`? An enum? Casting an enum to int with `(int)e` is probably free, parsing a string isn't.

Comment: Its an Enum. So, i think there's no need to declare a variable.

Comment: @UserM In that case, why isn't `someDomain.someValue` using the same enum?  Why is it an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the constant value once will likely improve the performance of this loop.

That being said, it is unlikely that this is a performance bottleneck.  Until you've profiled your application, and discovered that this is an actual issue, I would not necessarily worry about this level of micro-optimization.

Instead, I would focus on making your code the most readable possible.  Personally, I think making a variable would be more readable and maintainable, in this case.  I would write the above as:

```
// Why is this the wrong type in the first place?
var paymentPending = Convert.ToInt32(DomainConstants.PaymentPending); 

foreach(var domain in someDomains.Where(sd => sd.Value != paymentPending)
{
   // Do something with domain
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally, your concern is perfectly valid and your way of thinking is correct, because calculating something once and then "caching" it is a valid technique to improve the performance of a program. However, it usually applies to things that are large and complex to calculate, like structures parsed from files, dynamically generated images, etc.

A simple number parsing doesn't cause any easily observable performance bottleneck, so moving it out of the loop won't give any observable improvement, at least if the loop repetition count is of the order you claim.

In this particular example, you should more or less go for readability. If you ever get involved in a project that has execution time requirements, chances are you'll already know many more techniques for achieving a performance boost (a number of which will be considerably more effective than the one in question) and how to apply each one.

Comment: Thanks, Theodoros... Actually I have to improve the performance of my application and I can't find any areas of improvements. So I started with the basics... If that can help..

Comment: @UserM In that case, you should run your application through a profiler.  That will highlight areas where you should focus.  Trying to improve your application perf. by "looking through the code" will only cause frustration and pain.